# Confused about the solution to a problem in IPhO 2001

Tags: homework-and-exercises, orbital-motion

The problem statement is thus. "Assume  that M >> m<sub>0</sub>,  so  that the  ordinary  star  is basically rotating around the  neutron star in  a
circular orbit of radius r<sub>0</sub>. Assume  that  the  ordinary star starts emitting  gas  toward  the  neutron star  with a speed v<sub>0</sub> relative to the ordinary  star (see Fig. 2). Assuming that the neutron star  is  the dominant gravitational  force  in  this  problem and  neglecting the  orbital  changes  of  the  ordinary star  find  the distance of  closest  approach r<sub>f</sub> shown in  Fig.  2.." (ttp://ipho.org/problems-and-solutions/2001/IPhO2001-Theo%20Questions(pdf).pdf)

[image]

The solution of the problem (ttp://ipho.org/problems-and-solutions/2001/IPhO2001-Theo%20Solutions(pdf).pdf) introduces a quantity r without definition. It is used for angular momentum calculations such as: mr<sup>2</sup>ω = m<sub>0</sub>r<sub>0</sub><sup>2</sup>ω<sub>0</sub>, where ω<sub>0</sub> is the ordinary stars angular velocity relative to the neutron star when it starts ejecting gas. Here is most of the rest of the solution [image]

After thinking more about the problem I'm pretty sure r<sub>f</sub> is supposed to apply to the ejected gas, dm, but I still don't know what r is referring to.

Comment: I did this problem a few years ago. The solutions are wrong, and where they aren't wrong they're overly complicated. Keep in mind that the problems and solutions are often edited on the fly the day before the competition, don't trust them too much.